# When and where is _DEBUG defined?

Tags: debugging, gcc, c-preprocessor, compiler-options

I have the following sample code in one of my header files:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define _DEBUG_NEW_REDEFINE_NEW 0
#include "debug_new.h"
#else
#define DEBUG_NEW new
#endif
```

The application which includes this header file is compiled using gcc compiler with `-DDEBUG` option.

Question:

Is `_DEBUG` is defined because of the `-DDEBUG` option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-DDEBUG` will only define `DEBUG`, not `_DEBUG`. To figure out why (or if) `_DEBUG` is getting defined, try building the source file that includes that header with

```
gcc --other_options source_file.cc -E -dD -o source_file.ii
```

(You may have to remove another `-o` flag in the command line.) Then *source_file*.ii will include #define lines for every macro that was defined, and `# <lineno> <header>` lines each time it changes header files.

You can read http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-dD-946 to see exactly what `-dD` does.